# How to use order by when using the group by in LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

I have written a LINQ query to display the total number of students supervised by each faculty staff in order of faculty staff's name.

```
int count;
int key;
var myQuery = from s in Students
join f in Faculties
on s.FID equals f.FID
group f by f.FLast + ' ' + f.FFirst into grp
select new {key = grp.Key, count = grp.Count()};
myQuery.Dump();
```

This query spits out the result:

```
Brown Jonnel  1 
Zhulin Mark   1 
Marx Teresa   3 
Langley Colin 1
```

which is correct. However, there are two things I want to do this result. First I want to order it by the staff name, and second, I want to give those column headers aliases. How do I do this in LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myQuery = from s in Students
              join f in Faculties
              on s.FID equals f.FID
              group f by f.FLast + ' ' + f.FFirst into grp
              select new { StaffName = grp.Key //give column headers aliases
              , count = grp.Count() };            
myQuery.ToList().OrderBy(w=>w.StaffName)//order it by the staff name
.Dump();
```

[image]

Hope it help you :-)